# C# LINQ Invalid return type

Tags: c#, linq

```
public static IEnumerable<(string upper, string lower)> SelectByCase()
{
    string[] words = { "aPPLE", "BlUeBeRrY", "cHeRry" };

    var wordsUpperAndLower =
        from s in words
        select new { Upper = s.ToUpperInvariant(), Lower = s.ToLowerInvariant() };


    return wordsUpperAndLower;
}
```

Hello, I need a little help. I'm trying to return variable `wordsUpperAndLower` but have issue *"Cannot convert expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<{string ToUpperInvariant, string ToLowerInvariant}>' to return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(string upper, string lower)>'"*

What is the problem?

Comment: Your projection uses an anonymous type (`new { ... }`) whereas your return type uses a tuple `(string upper, string lower)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your using an anonymous type you should be selecting using a tuple

```
public static IEnumerable<(string upper, string lower)> SelectByCase()
{
    string[] words = { "aPPLE", "BlUeBeRrY", "cHeRry" };
    //Sorry I took the liberty to use the fluent syntax
    return words.Select(x => 
    { 
       return (s.ToUpperInvariant(),s.ToLowerInvariant());
    });
}
```

**Note:**  It probably can be inlined like so but I'm not near my IDE to verify whether the compiler will get confused

```
return words.Select(s =>(s.ToUpperInvariant(), s.ToLowerInvariant()));
```

Comment: I think this can be inlined to `return words.Select(s =>(s.ToUpperInvariant(), s.ToLowerInvariant()));` Also you specify `x` as the iterating var but use `s` in the Select expression

Comment: It probably can be, but I know the compiler gets annoyed sometimes and I wasn't by my IDE to make sure